# error when getting data from another class

Tags: java, android, methods, compiler-errors, return

I am creating a simple Android app. The part I am having trouble is when I am trying to get a `String` value from the class `randomFailureQuotes` the method that is important is as follows

```
public String getQuote(String[] quotes, int indexPosition) {
    String quoteToBeDisplayed = new String(quotes[indexPosition]);
    return quotes[indexPosition];
}
```

I try to make this the label of a textView with this code in my `EditorActivity` class the code for this is as follows.

```
randomFailureQuotes quote = new randomFailureQuotes();
    String Fq = quote.getQuote;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_editor);
    TextView quoteDisplay = new TextView(this);
    quoteDisplay.setText(Fq);
```

The error is with when I am trying to set a string value named Fq to the value that the method `getQuote` returns. The IDE says **it can't find the symbol getQuote**. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Feel free to point out any other unrelated errors in my code as I am new at Java and Android development and would love to learn.

EDIT
as requested by RScotCarson here is the rest of my code from both classes
randomFailureQuotes

```
    public class randomFailureQuotes {
    List<String> quotes = new ArrayList<>();

    double indexPosition = (Math.random() * 4);

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        quotes.add("Failure Does't mean the game is over, it means try again with Experience");
        quotes.add("Failure is an event not a person. Yesterday ended Last night - Zig Ziglar");
        quotes.add("We learn from failure not success");
        quotes.add("If you're not prepared to be wrong, you'll never come up with anything original - Ken Robinson");
       }

    public String getQuote(String[] quotes, int indexPosition) {
        String quoteToBeDisplayed = new String(quotes[indexPosition]);
        return quotes[indexPosition];
    }

}
```

EditorActivity

```
    package com.example.slick.thegiftoffailure;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
    import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import java.util.Random;

    import static android.R.attr.id;

    public class EditorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //the toolbar
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            // the quote label
        randomFailureQuotes quote = new randomFailureQuotes();
        String Fq = quote.getQuote();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_editor);
        TextView quoteDisplay = new TextView(this);
        quoteDisplay.setText(Fq);

    }

}
```

Comment: your method `getQuote` require parameter which is `getQuote(String[], int)`

Comment: @Baby I don't understand what you are trying to say I have those arguments in my randomFailureQuotes

Comment: Yes you have that in your method definition. but you didnt include them when you call your method here `String Fq = quote.getQuote;`.

Comment: to simply try it, replace `String Fq = quote.getQuote;` with `String Fq = quote.getQuote({"Hello", World"}, 1);`

Comment: @Baby It says array initializer is not allowed here.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the user guidelines on how to ask a good question before posting a question (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's take a look at your getQuote definition:

```
public String getQuote(String[] quotes, int indexPosition)
```

It takes in an array of Strings as well as a position used to index into the array. That means that when you call getQuote it should look more like this...

```
// quotes is an array declared and instantiated previously
// index is an integer that is also declared and instantiated previously
String Fq = quote.getQuote(quotes, index)
```

From your question it seems like quote exists in another class. Can you please post the rest of your code from both classes?

If both the index and the array of quotes belong to the RandomFailureQuotes class as member, then you don't need to pass them in to the method as long as they have been instantiated.

**EDIT**
After the OP provided the extra code, the issue is in the randomFailureQuotes class has a few issues.

- onCreate() is NOT a constructor. onCreate is a part of the Android framework and is part of the [Activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html). A standard Java class looks like this...

RandomFailureQuote.java

```
// It is Java convention to have class names capitalized each word
public class RandomFailureQuotes {

    private List<String> quotes = new ArrayList<>();

    // The constructor does not need any arguments since you are 
    // generating the quotes yourself.
    public RandomFailureQuotes() {
        quotes.add("Failure Does't mean the game is over, it means try again with Experience");
        quotes.add("Failure is an event not a person. Yesterday ended Last night - Zig Ziglar");
        quotes.add("We learn from failure not success");
        quotes.add("If you're not prepared to be wrong, you'll never come       up with anything original - Ken Robinson");
    }

    // Because the index and quotes array are member variables, 
    // you do not need the arguments in the method definition. 
    // Also, to get a random number each time you get a quote
    // you will need to move the random variable to the method.
    // you will need to cast the double value of indexPosition to an int                   value 
    public String getQuote() {
        double indexPosition = (Math.random() * 4);
        String quoteToBeDisplayed = quotes.get((int) indexPosition);
        return quoteToBeDisplayed;
    }
}
```

As for the EditorActivity, there are issues there as well. I'm assuming you're not even using the toolbar, so I'm going to remove that from the activity and the activity_layout.xml file.

EditorActivity.java

```
package com.example.slick.thegiftoffailure;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class EditorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_editor);

        // the quote label
        randomFailureQuotes quote = new randomFailureQuotes();
        String Fq = quote.getQuote();

        // You must retrieve the textview from your 
        // activity_layout.xml file
        TextView quoteDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        quoteDisplay.setText(Fq);
    }
}
```

I then modified the xml to only have one TextView that displays a single failure quote. Note that the app will have to be restarted for it to choose a different quote.

activity_editor.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/content_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally, from a developer, I suggest you spend some time learning Java before jumping in to Android. There are intricacies to both that take a little time to learn. There are a million step-y-step tutorials out there on the web to get you started with both. Find one you like and follow it closely! Good luck learning!

Comment: Apparently quotes.get only accepts int not double data types. So I edited your code by casting the double to an int. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You create a new object of type randomFailureQuotes called quote. You didn't pass in parameters for the object and then you tried to access the getQuote data member inside of the newly created object directly. If you want to use the getQuote function you would at least need to include parenthesis so it looks like this: quote.getQuote()

But remember your getQuote function is expecting an array of strings with an index in the array.

getQuote should return a string, which should be fine. It will return the string that is stored at the index value inside of the String array. BUt you need to ensure that you have either passed in the String array and value or defined it in the default constructor.

Answer (score -1):

String Fq = quote.getQuote;

This refers to a member variable (field) called getQuote.  It is nowhere defined.

The method getQuote() is unrelated. Variable names and method names occupy distinct namespaces.